# Need Jquery to read CSV file on page load

Tags: jquery, csv

I found the code for reading CSV into a table through a file search input but cannot figure out how to make it automatically read a CSV file on page load.

Here is the code for the CSV to table from the [googlecode](http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/git/examples/file-handling.html).

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
if(isAPIAvailable()) {
  $('#files').bind('change', handleFileSelect);
}
});

function isAPIAvailable() {
// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
  return true;
} else {
  // source: File API availability - http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi
  // source: <output> availability - http://html5doctor.com/the-output-element/
  document.writeln('The HTML5 APIs used in this form are only available in the following browsers:<br />');
  // 6.0 File API & 13.0 <output>
  document.writeln(' - Google Chrome: 13.0 or later<br />');
  // 3.6 File API & 6.0 <output>
  document.writeln(' - Mozilla Firefox: 6.0 or later<br />');
  // 10.0 File API & 10.0 <output>
  document.writeln(' - Internet Explorer: Not supported (partial support expected in 10.0)<br />');
  // ? File API & 5.1 <output>
  document.writeln(' - Safari: Not supported<br />');
  // ? File API & 9.2 <output>
  document.writeln(' - Opera: Not supported');
  return false;
}
 }

 function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
var file = files[0];

// read the file metadata
var output = ''
    output += '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + escape(file.name) + '</span><br />\n';
    output += ' - FileType: ' + (file.type || 'n/a') + '<br />\n';
    output += ' - FileSize: ' + file.size + ' bytes<br />\n';
    output += ' - LastModified: ' + (file.lastModifiedDate ? file.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a') + '<br />\n';

// read the file contents
printTable(file);

// post the results
$('#list').append(output);
 }

 function printTable(file) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file);
reader.onload = function(event){
  var csv = event.target.result;
  var data = $.csv.toArrays(csv);
  var html = '';
  for(var row in data) {
    html += '<tr>\r\n';
    for(var item in data[row]) {
      html += '<td>' + data[row][item] + '</td>\r\n';
    }
    html += '</tr>\r\n';
  }
  $('#contents').html(html);
};
reader.onerror = function(){ alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName); };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't automatically load local files from html, because of sandbox security concern.
Otherwise, you can image that, hacker could easily create some fishing websites to auto upload your local files to their server and retrieve the sensitive data.

Comment: That's right. If the CSV file is stored on the client side, you'll have to make the client initiate the file reading, such as by dragging and dropping them (uploading to server). If the CSV file is stored on the server tho it's a different story.

Comment: And if the CSV file was stored on the server side, would it be possible or is that still a security concern?

Comment: if they are on the server side, and on the same domain, yes you can directly access the content by normal ajax call.